# Can't make sense of this phrase

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

In the text:

"Renters are reeling with sticker shock as they discover just how aggressively New York’s housing market is bouncing back."

Is: "reeling with sticker shock"

same as:

"reeling from the shock"?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sticker_shock

Comment: @user142439 I realize my answer made an assumption. Can you clarify, are you asking about the phrase "sticker shock," or about the choice of preposition "with" or "from"?

Comment: @Andy Bonner, you've made the right assumption and I think it stems from the fact I used the "from" preposition when I have rewtiten the phrase otherwise I had kept the "with" and mentioned only the sticker shock part

Answer (score -1):

If your question focuses on "reeling with" vs "reeling from," they're equivalent in usage. Although "from" makes sense (sticker shock is *causing* them to reel), this construction is similar to the way one would discuss medical symptoms: "I'm burning *with* fever." "I'm in bed *with* a headache." There would be nothing wrong with "from," though, and in some usages it would be the only appropriate choice ("The boxer, still reeling *from* his opponent's punch..."). The difference in these examples is that reeling is a condition that the subjects are in, and so is sticker shock (and fever, and headache). A punch is not. So the "___ing *with*" construction works when a condition is being linked to another condition.